# How to send email from windows form app with log4net

Tags: winforms, email, .net-3.5, log4net

I have set up log4net in my C# 3.5 windows form application.  I am looking for how to send email from a client pc with log4net.  The SMTPAppender requires knowledge of SMTPHost and the examples I've seen are for web applications.

Is there a way to send email from an application that will work on any client's computer that may or may not be in a domain or network. I guess I would also need to be able to check if there is a connection available.

I've searched for an answer but I don't have much experience programming with email or the web to know what to look for.  Any ideas to steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# SmtpClient is quite right for your needs. here's some sample code (host is an ip address or host name, and the port is usually 25, but not necessarily) :

```
public static void SendMail(
                                    string host,
                                    int port,
                                    SmtpAuthentication authentication,
                                    string userName,
                                    string password,
                                    string from,
                                    string to,
                                    string cc,
                                    string subject,
                                    string body,
                                    string[] attachments)
        {
            // Create and configure the smtp client
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            if (host != null && host.Length > 0)
            {
                smtpClient.Host = host;
            }

            smtpClient.Port = port;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            if (authentication == SmtpAuthentication.Basic)
            {
                // Perform basic authentication
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            }
            else if (authentication == SmtpAuthentication.Ntlm)
            {
                // Perform integrated authentication (NTLM)
                smtpClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mailMessage.To.Add(to);
            mailMessage.CC.Add(cc);

            foreach (string attachement in attachments)
            {
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachement));
            }

            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure of what to use for the host string. Is it the IP address of the PC?  
So to work on every machine I should use CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials for authentication?

Comment: try asking your sysadmin for the host name. as for credentials, default network credentials should work on all machines. you should only supply your mailbox username and password.